# Inconsistent `body_class()` function

Tags: css, page-template

Here's my scenario:

1. I'm using `body_class()` in my `<body>` tag as per the Codex instructions
2. I've created *specialized page templates* (as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Specialized_Page_Template)) for the following pages:

   - Home: `page-home.php`
   - Services: `page-services.php`
   - About: `page-about.php`
   - Contact: `page-contact.php`
3. The page templates themselves load just fine.
4. The problem begins with the classes being returned by `body_class()`: for the first two pages it works fine, returning `.page-template-page-home-php` and `.page-template-page-services-php` respectively. For the other two pages it just returns `.page-template-default`, despite the fact that it is *clearly* not using the default page templates.

**Does anyone know what might be causing this?**

I know several ways of forcing it to add the classes, so I'm not looking for a workaround. I'm just wondering why this functionality doesn't seem to work correctly out-of-the-box.

**UPDATE:** Having poked around the `body_class()` function I've narrowed down the cause; it seems the page templates for those two pages hadn't been saved to the post meta table. The next question is what may have caused this.

Comment: the class `.page-template-{name}-php` appears when you've assigned a custom page template under the Page Attributes meta box, but your template names appear to be following the `page-{slug}.php` naming convention. Is it possible you are confusing the two types of page templates?

Comment: I think Milo has it.  When editing the page, if "default template" is assigned, the template hierarchy will use the correct PHP file (slug in your case) but not display a unique class.

Comment: @milo Unfortunately, no. I'm only using *specialized page templates* (i.e the `page-{slug}.php` convention you mentioned). I'm not using any *custom page templates* (i.e with the template name at the top of the file). Therefore I don't even have a Page Attributes meta box. 
As an aside, doesn't it make you wish WordPress would gives these clearer names? It *is* very possible to confuse the two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @milo prompted me to take a closer look, and I realised I was chasing a false positive. The About page and Contact page were actually displaying the *correct* behaviour; it was Home and Services that were wrong. It seems at some point those two pages *did* have custom page templates, which were later turned into specialized page templates. However, their body classes persisted.

The important thing to take away is: **when a custom page template is removed/deleted *and* there are no other custom page templates to fallback to, the value is *not* cleared from the post meta, which means it will continue to show those body classes until a new template is assigned.**

I will check if this is logged as an issue on the WP Trac later on today.